# Volume of 3 overlapped spheres with equal radii

Tags: volume, spheres

There is a solid of three spheres overlapped with equal radii. Each sphere surfaces passes the centers of other two spheres. What is the equation to find the volume of this solid?

[Triple Bubble Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9fO8.jpg)

*this image is found in MathOverflow